# scraping only 1 quote multiple time in selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrapr quotes from good reads, I search about quotes in the list `search_by_keyword` and I append these quotes into a csv file with two columns the text column which includes the quotes, and the hobby column which includes the `label_in_csv`.

However, the result is a the same quote in all the 50 index in the text column. I am trying to do this using selenium in google colab;

Here is the code:

```
label_in_csv = 'الموسيقي' 
search_by_keyword=["مزيكا"] 




df_p=pd.DataFrame()





for syn in search_by_keyword:
    ua = UserAgent()
    userAgent = ua.random
    #print(userAgent)
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')
    proxy= ['185.47.223.53','110.74.222.106','59.153.18.170','151.232.72.13']
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
    
    
    driver.header_overrides = {
        'user-agent': userAgent,
            }
    driver.get("https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/tag/")
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    search_area = driver.find_element_by_id('id')
    search_area.send_keys(syn,Keys.ENTER)
    for j in range (50): maximum per label

      for i in  driver.find_elements_by_class_name('quoteText'):
            text= i.text
            text= text.splitlines()
            #if wordnet.synsets(text[0].split()[-1].replace(".”", "")):
            
            
            df_p_tmp = pd.DataFrame({'text':text[0],'hobby':[label_in_csv]})
            print(text[0])
            df_p = pd.concat([df_p,df_p_tmp])

        try:
           driver.find_element_by_class_name('next_page').click()
        except NoSuchElementException:
         search_area = driver.find_element_by_id('id')
         
     df_p.to_csv('{}_hobby.csv'.format(syn))
            
            break



print(len(df_p))
```

Any idea?

Comment: As an aside, repeatedly concatenating/appending DataFrames is rarely a good idea. It's better to create a temporary/intermediate data structure, and create the entire DF at once when you're done.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried to do so with list but also the same quote is kept appending to the list ended up having one list of length 50 with only quote kept repeating 50 times:(

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?